# subprocess.run returns PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Tags: python, python-3.x, permissions, subprocess, exe

I'm trying to run an .exe via python's subprocess.run.  The command executes successfully in command prompt, but when I run the below command with Python 3.6 it returns **PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied**

```
subprocess.run([r'"C:\Temp\KML2WF\KML2WF.exe" --image "C:\Temp\HR3700_R2_Q50.jpg" --kml "C:\Temp\doc.kml"'])
```

The KML2WF.exe creates another file in the same directory as the --image path, which I have access to.

Does someone know how I can fix this error?

Comment: Try launching the python3.6 as administrator and run the command and also make sure you have all the permissions for system to access that particular folder or exe

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to resolve the error even though the user account and SYSTEM user had full privileges to the folder and exe.  I worked around the error by creating a batch file and executing the .bat using the subprocess.run function.